# Project structure of Spring MVC and google polymer

Tags: spring-mvc, polymer

I am trying to make an spring MVC based application with google polymer in front end.I am novice in google polymer

Can anyone help me with the project structure, where and how to arrange the polymer library?

Comment: Here is a link that might help you: https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/31/webinar-replay-building-a-secure-polymer-app-with-spring-backend

Answer (score 1):

So after some readings, i found the answer, might be useful to others

1. The UI application build in Polymer is single page application which consumes web services form another application in spring (could be anything else)
2. the two applications deployed separately , there is no need to bundle these together, instead these shouldn't be.